# How do I make a class component method accessible outside of the component in React and Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I need to be able to call a class component's methods outside of the class as I am building a component library that compiles to `umd` and then is available via the `window` object.

At the moment the methods in my classes are private but I want to make them 'callable' from outside. I have seen that it can be done using React `refs`, but I can only find specific examples where `ref` is used to make a classes methods available to other components.

```js
import React, { Component, ReactElement } from 'react';


interface DashboardProps {
  props?: Function;
}

interface DashboardState {
  ColorToggled: boolean;
  myRef?: Function;
  current?: Function;
}

class Dashboard extends Component<DashboardProps, DashboardState> {
  private myRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

  constructor(props: DashboardProps) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      colorToggled: false,
    };
  }


  public changeColor = (): void => { // I want to make this method accessible outside of the component
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      colorToggled: !prevState.colorToggled,
    }));
  };

  render(): ReactElement {
    // console.log(this.current.myRef();
    return (
      <>
        <div
          role="textbox"
          tabIndex={0}
          style={{
            padding: '20px',
            backgroundColor: this.state.colorToggled === true ? '#f00' : '#00f',
          }}
        >
          <br />
        </div>
        <input type="text" ref={this.myRef} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

I have only just starting putting the above together so it is not functional at all but not quite sure how to progress.

Comment: Why not make the color a prop and update your component that way?

Comment: Otherwise you can indeed do `youcomponent.current.changeColor()` to call the method directly.

Comment: I don't want to use props in this case - I'm specifically trying to find a way of accessing methods from outside their classes :)

Comment: You can use `static`, and use it like so, `ComponentClass.functionName()`

Comment: thanks @Miller, so I would use `static changeColor` in this case?

Comment: Indeed, then you make it callable without using the `new` keyword

Comment: like this, https://codesandbox.io/s/new-haze-tcng3

Comment: @Miller, static wouldn't work because `this` would not refer to the component instance but to the class. So he would be setting the state on basically nothing.

Comment: My bad, i was totally not checking the content of changeColor, only the `call from outside aspect`. But you are right, because its called from outside the Component. I think that your idea will not be the solution to achieve your goal tbh.

Comment: Thanks @Miller I can now access the method outside of the class but I cannot use 'this', so I cannot `this.setState` as the above comment suggests. How can I call the method and `setState` from it?

Comment: If you really need this, a quit nasty solution could be like so, https://codesandbox.io/s/new-haze-tcng3

Basically, on mount you set the function to a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a component library, almost always one or multiple components like `Dashboard` are exported as a module (in your case with UMD also on the global scope) and the package consumer provides the React runtime. That also means, you can rely on the React environment in the library - just pass in props to your root component from the client.

If you really wanted to call a public method on a class component imperatively from another component, you could do that with [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs), as you said.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQokscA3nJQHYAmWUcAvnCIlylPDAC0XErToNw0eGQB0AelQwAngBssqZblSpZdLWCxwAyjGQwLAXlZ04cXBG3QAKhADmP3VwAXHAARhDuOBz0-PR0uNpo6AAiaAAWYchQXC5YAB523OjY4soAwiSQHFgcMAA8LPwANFY2dgB8Ti4atg6dLq7uXr7+WEFCyNqoWM4CsS6cPFAAFACUffNYMACuUBxwSzP9cLVcwABurglGAHLIIFj2ZACCYGBkbYdHx6kAjG3lHj4MGGAWCLGsUGAHB8SxgqWA+m6dgMgyg3j8ARW-Fqql+Hy+x1UpzO+P6K3oLn4chcuFSyGhWAB0DgjlWwTOEGA2XsHRYnzhCOUUxg1h6SzAlDOorsLI6Sz5BLcgPRIzGAEIJVgpa0sCjlSDRp9+CtyTMYnQqXEIBwNHAXmAWfs1jy+rp4G5wNgCI7ivgDGI7F7ailUOkIJkuG1VhT2JsdnsDkcTudSUmQlsYMC9tbStpgLgANb2FirWUDT1YAgGHacGBqgx0hlM5ZY1NfFW6AaAz4uHHpzPWtu9kNhiOxgjFj1gL2CVRtGgsVRIWoAcQ8IQm5XAcDniFUVKTRJTM1N5roC14S1q9p3bWa0lwW3uNWUPk2AFFdM+YAAhTQASS4JYKHCGAyBNeggA)

Dashboard with public `changeColor` method:

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  ...
  changeColor = (): void => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      colorToggled: !prevState.colorToggled
    }));
  };
}
```

(for function components there is [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle))

Add a ref to Dashboard and invoke `changeColor`:

```
const App = () => {
  let compRef = React.createRef<ColorComp>();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => compRef.current!.changeColor()}>
        Toggle color
      </button>
      <ColorComp ref={compRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

There are possibly much more alternatives, to name only a few:

- [Custom DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) (compare [Microfrontends](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html)),
- [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) communication between window objects,
- Register a method callback on `window` in `componentDidMount`

These have to be justified somehow, as they add complexity and coupling to the architecture. So I would stick to the first section (via props and/or refs), unless you really have special requirements.

Hope, that helps.

Comment: Thanks @ford04, that's a great explanation and example. So let's say I use the ref approach and have a umd as you say and have the component in the global scope / window object. How do I then call a method inside the class component using `refs`? In the playground you created only exposes a child's method to it's parent react component. Many thanks!

Comment: As said, parent to child comp communication is the only use case applicable for `ref`, as `ref`s do only exist inside `React` environment. I wanted to focus on showing you the instance method invocation of class components with `ref`s in the answer. From "outside", you won't be able to call a component method directly, unless you share this method reference in the module or global scope with the client. That been said, it is hard to give a solution for latter case, as it would require more information about your project to weigh pros and cons. Have a look the example list for some inspiration.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No worries, hope it has helped a bit nonetheless.